# Can we read data from CLOB or TEXT data type column in EnterpriseDB 9.2

Tags: postgresql, clob, enterprisedb

I am using **EnterpriseDB 9.2 advanced server** (an Oracle compatible **PostgreSQL fork**) and I want to read data from a clob or text type data type column using `getClob()` method.

I'm getting error when trying:

> org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: Bad value for type long :
>   adminuser@domainUser Logged In
>   Sucessfully   at
>   org.postgresql.jdbc2.AbstractJdbc2ResultSet.toLong(AbstractJdbc2ResultSet.java:2‌​971)
>   at
>   org.postgresql.jdbc2.AbstractJdbc2ResultSet.getLong(AbstractJdbc2ResultSet.java:‌​2163)
>   at
>   org.postgresql.jdbc2.AbstractJdbc2ResultSet.getClob(AbstractJdbc2ResultSet.java:‌​436)

So is it possible to read data from above mentioned scenario using any technique in postgresql?

Comment: By "oracle compatible" - Do you mean EnterpriseDB Advanced Server? Please be specific about thwat *exactly* you are running. Show the *exact* error messsage with full stack trace. Show the code you're running. Details pleae.

Comment: ya i mean yes i'm using EnterpriseDB Advanced Server,org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: Bad value for type long : <user><name>adminuser@domain</name><message>User Logged In Sucessfully</message></user>
 at org.postgresql.jdbc2.AbstractJdbc2ResultSet.toLong(AbstractJdbc2ResultSet.java:2971)
 at org.postgresql.jdbc2.AbstractJdbc2ResultSet.getLong(AbstractJdbc2ResultSet.java:2163)
 at org.postgresql.jdbc2.AbstractJdbc2ResultSet.getClob(AbstractJdbc2ResultSet.java:436)

Comment: Use `getString()` - that will work in Oracle and Postgres (provided you use an up-to-date driver for Oracle)

Comment: thank you, it's working means getString() is working for reading the clob or text data in postgresql 9.2, oracle and sql server also.

Answer (score 0):

In a case of using Hibernate you can define the entity as shown below. The solution works well at least on PostgreSQL, H2 and HSQLDB (I didn't check other DBs):

```
@Column(columnDefinition = "CLOB")
String myClobField;
```